# Passing data from a query to mapView viewForAnnotation function

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am trying to display custom pins on an MKMapView. These pins will have a custom image as well as a UILabel that will display a value.

I was able to successfully create the custom pin, with label. Right now the label displays a static value. I queried the data from a backend service like parse, and saved the data for each point. That way when the user taps on a certain point i can display the data in the `viewController`, however I am not sure how to pass this data from my query method into the didSelectAnnotation and viewForAnnotation methods.

I also would like to change the static value that the label shows to one queried from the server. I tried to do this by creating a class called `CustomPointAnnotation`, which inherits from `MKPointAnnotation` and has an initializer with three properties. these properties are set during the query, so how can I access these properties in the `mapViewDidSelectAnnotationView`, and the `viewForAnnotation` functions so that I can use the data for my needs. (for things like setting the text for a label within the `viewController` to a property of that specific annotation).

Below is an image that shows the viewController and what I have so far:

[image]

Here is the custom point class:

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {

var price: String!
var streetName: String!
var ratingValue: Int!


init?(price: String, streetName: String, ratingValue: Int) {
    self.price = price
    self.streetName = streetName
    self.ratingValue = ratingValue
    super.init()
}
```

}

Below is the query that I run in viewDidLoad:

```
 func displayPoints() {
    let pointsQuery = PFQuery(className: "testLocation")
    let currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(location: locationManager.location)
    pointsQuery.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinMiles: 2)
    pointsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (points, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("number of spots: \(points?.count)")
            let spots = points! as [PFObject]
            for pinPoint in spots {
                let point = pinPoint["location"] as! PFGeoPoint
                let price = String(pinPoint["price"])
                let ratingValue = pinPoint["rating"] as! Int
                let streetName = "Park Street, San Francisco CA"
                self.customAnnotation = CustomPointAnnotation(price: price, streetName: streetName, ratingValue: ratingValue)

                //// PRINT DATA OBTAINED FOR TESTING PURPOSES///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                print(self.customAnnotation.price)
                print(self.customAnnotation.streetName)
                print(self.customAnnotation.ratingValue)
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                self.customAnnotation!.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)
                self.priceArray.append(pinPoint["price"])
                self.customAnnotation!.price = pinPoint["price"] as? String
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.customAnnotation!)


            }
        } else {
            JSSAlertView().danger(self, title: "something went wrong", text: "error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

here is the didSelectAnnotationView:

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    //var anot: MKAnnotation

    if ((view.annotation?.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation)) != nil){
        view.image = nil
    }

    for anot in mapView.annotations {
        print(mapView.annotations.count)
        let annotationView = mapView.viewForAnnotation(anot)
        if (annotationView != nil) {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "pin")
            priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        //priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        view.image = UIImage(named: "pinselected")
        print("image changed")

    }
}
```

and finally the viewForAnnotation method:

```
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation){
    return nil
}


    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        print("all custom images added")
        return nil
    }

   let reuseID = "identifier"

var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID)
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID, price: "13" )
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = false

    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }


                                                                                                                //let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
                                                                                                                //let annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil, price: "11")
                                                                                                                //annotationView!.addSubview(priceLabel)
    annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "pin.png")
    return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can down cast in swift with the as operator. In didSelectAnnotationView the annotationView has an annotation property. Your custom annotation view will have your custom annotation as its annotation property, so you can attempt to down cast it to your subclass by saying:

```
if let annotation = view.annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation
```

Assuming that's possible, you will then have access to your subclass's properties.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
        //var anot: MKAnnotation

    if ((view.annotation?.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation)) != nil){
        view.image = nil
    }

    for anot in mapView.annotations {
        print(mapView.annotations.count)
        let annotationView = mapView.viewForAnnotation(anot)
        if (annotationView != nil) {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "pin")
            priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        //priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()


    }
    view.image = UIImage(named: "pinselected")
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? CustomPointAnnotation
    {
        self.priceLabel.text = annotation.price //for example
        //update the rest of your UI
    }

    print("image changed")
}
```

Similarly in viewForAnnotation you can down cast the MKAnnotation to CustomPointAnnotation and MKAnnotationView to CustomAnnotationView.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation){
    return nil
}


    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        print("all custom images added")
        return nil
    }

   let reuseID = "identifier"
   let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
   var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as! CustomAnnotationView
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: cpa, reuseIdentifier: reuseID, price: cpa.price)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = false

    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = cpa
        annotationView?.price = cpa.price
    }

    annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "pin.png")
    return annotationView
}
```

Your CustomAnnotationView should update its price label when its price is set by implementing price's didSet.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!